# Identify Unique Browser / tab instance, e.g. User has 2 tabs open on mysite.com-identify each

Tags: asp.net, .net, browser, identify

I have read [this](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/unique-browser-id-t3951101p2.html) and many other links the past few days.

The problem is that I need to have a unique identifier for each tab or browser that a user has open for mysite.com (example site name)

I cannot use a unique session, as when I open mysite.com and have e.g. selected "carrots" in the session, then all the other tabs/browsers for mysite.com now has "carrots" in the specific session value.

But still the server obviously identifies each browser/tab uniquely. Is there a way to get hold of this unique browser/tab ID, or to create a unique one?

I am not referring to generating a unique ID oneself via JavaScript, I saw some good examples on StackOverflow. The problem would be that I'd need to implement it on each master page and carry it around between master/non master pages. Also for e.g. In my instance it won't work as I can have the browser open and it would generate 20 different IDs if I ran it 20 times across a few pages e.g. when I cannot transfer the value across ports.

So please, not to waste everyone's time, this is not a random GUID creation question, this question relates to obtaining a unique recreatable ID (if it gets lost)for each tab/browser, preferably identifying by the link to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a big topic you've touched on.
If you only need to persist the ID during a form submit, you can take the approach of the client-side `window.name` property and use the `window.onload` to propagate a hidden field with that value.
But this won't work when user is following hyper-links (click on a link on a site).
onload: check if `window.name` is set; if not set, assign a GUID. if set, set a hidden field=`window.name`.  So, on submit, your form will have the hidden field with the `window.name` GUID.

You can also use the HTML5 `window.sessionStorage` which will solve all your troubles, but that don't work on older browsers.

If you need support backward-browser AND non-submit type, then you will need to write some pretty complex cookie/session management on the client side. Not pretty.  Just hope the above 2 is sufficient.

Comment: This (window.sessionStorage) looks great thanks. We currently only allow IE7 and later. When I google 'windows.sessionStorage', I get to http://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/ which says that the script will work with every "A-grade browser". Does IE7 count as an  "A-grade browser"?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, IE7 is NOT (imho) an A-grade browser *lol*
Seriously, the sessionStorage only works on HTML5 compliant browsers and IE7 is ancient (I don't think anyone uses it anymore).
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html5.html

The minimum browser that I (and company) support is IE8.  But if you really need to support pre-IE8, then you will need to check the browser version and then explore the use of userData Behaviour which goes back to IE5. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531424(VS.85).aspx